# Pushbullet Integration with Amazon Echo (Alexa)

Tags: pushbullet

Do you have any intention to integrate your service with Amazon Echo (Alexa)? I believe it would be a great opportunity for you, because currently there is no easy way to connect your phone to the Amazon Echo. I know it would save me several missed calls if my Amazon Echo would ring when my phone rings. Is there any way to do this currently though my PC? When I am at home, I tend to leave my phone charging and usually cannot hear when I am receiving a call. If I can connect it to a device that would ring louder, such as the amazon echo or my pc, it would be very useful and I think a lot of others would find this feature beneficial as well if it were available and they knew it existed.

Comment: Been about two years, but for what it's worth, I hope you found something! 

I'd love to be able to play back notifications or reminders I send to myself for later.

Answer (score 0):

The Echo doesn't work like that.  It can only respond to input from the user, it cannot initiate an interaction.  To implement what you have described you would have to start the conversation by asking the echo "Alexa, do I have an incoming call" and she could then check and answer.

Update: Amazon just released the Echo Connect in Feb 2018.  It turns your Echo into a speaker phone.  Search for it on Amazon.

Comment: I find that to be untrue, Twitch has a notification sound when it receives a notification. The same could be applied to a call easily.

Comment: If you have code that does this, please post a link to it.  Saying that another product can do it so it must be easy does not make it so.

Comment: I was simply stating the framework should already be there by logic. I do not have the code and wait to see some myself.